# Forward fill columns if row value is equal to x - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to forward fill specific columns but only where a row is equal to a certain value. For instance, using the df below, I want to .ffill() Val1, Val2, Helper where rows in Helper = 'Forward'. Everything else should remain the same.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({   
        'Col' : ['X',np.nan,np.nan,'Y',np.nan,'Z',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],  
        'Val1' : ['B',np.nan,np.nan,'A',np.nan,'C',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],   
        'Val2' : ['A',np.nan,np.nan,'C',np.nan,'C',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],                 
        'Helper' : ['No',np.nan,np.nan,'Forward',np.nan,'Held',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],                  
        })

mask = df['Helper'].str.contains('Forward', na = True)

df.loc[mask, 'Val1'] = df['Val1']
df['Val1'] = df['Val1'].ffill()
df.loc[mask, 'Val1'] = np.nan
```

Intended Output:

```
   Col Val1 Val2   Helper
0    X    B    A       No
1  NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN
3    Y    A    C  Forward
4  NaN    A    C  Forward
5    Z    C    C     Held
6  NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN
7  NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN
8  NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
df.update(df.loc[df['Helper'].str.contains('Forward').ffill(), ['Val1','Val2','Helper']].ffill())
```

**Output**

```
print(df)
   Col     Val1     Val2    Helper
0   X         B     A       No
1   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   Y         A     C       Forward
4   NaN       A     C       Forward
5   Z         C     C       Held
6   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
7   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
8   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: thanks @moys. Great clean answer. Didn't even know about `update`

Answer (score 1):

Create a mask after forward fill and then use the condition to fill the column using `np.where`

```
>>> m = df['Helper'].ffill().str.contains('Forward')
>>> req_cols = ['Val1', 'Val2', 'Helper']
>>> df[cols] = np.where(m, df[cols].ffill(), df[cols])
>>> df
   Col Val1 Val2   Helper
0    X    B    A       No
1  NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN
3    Y    A    C  Forward
4  NaN    A    C  Forward
5    Z    C    C     Held
6  NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN
7  NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN
8  NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN
```